New Google place api using google OAuth, ask failed to refresh token
I have a Express.js backend, and i want to use Google new place API, so I need to to auth throw Oauth, the issue after a certain amount of time around one day I need to reauthorize the app, I get this error:
Token is expiring, refreshing...
Failed to refresh token: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"reauth related error (invalid_rapt)","error_uri":"https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756","error_subtype":"invalid_rapt"}
Authorize this app by visiting this URL: URL here.

I thought it was a one time actions, to authorize with link.

please edit your question and include your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is okey i figure out the issue, it was in my admin console i had to make the app as trusted one.

I just understand the issue is in my google console (api contols Security-> API controls->App access control), where i don't have my server app trusted one
